# MSTest.exe (VS2012) crashes QTAgent32.exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, mstest

i am trying to execute our tests via cmdline.
I use VS2012, but i always get this error:

[image: error]

When i run the tests directly in VS2010 on the same machine they run fine.
I can't use  VS2010 for cmdline because we have the wrong license ( assembly finding doesn't work ) so i have to use 2012.
All Windows updates are present.

Has somebody had similar issues with MSTest/VS2012 ?

Comment: That's an ExecutionEngineException, a hard crash in the CLR.  Normally caused by unmanaged code that corrupts the garbage collected heap.  Test failed, perhaps.  Whatever mysterious licensing issue you have is probably going to be a *lot* easier to fix than trying to fix this crash.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The odd thing is, those tests run fine on another build agent which i set up today. We have VS2010 Prof licenses which don't support MSTest cmdline tets with assembly discovery and our IT won't buy upgrade licenses.

Comment: It seems that Update1 or 2 of VS2012 breaks Tests with .NET 3.5 so did a complete uninstall and reinstalled without updates and now our tests are running again.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to keep VS 2012 update 2, 3, or 4 installed, you can try the below workaround:

Run the below commands in the command line:

```
DEL /S %windir%\*Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.AssemblyResolver.ni.dll* 
DEL /S %windir%\*Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.ExecutionCommon.ni.dll*
```

This is a [workaround](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/783668/qtagent32-35-exe-qtagent32-exe-system-executionengineexception-running-unittest-in-vs2012-2) provided by Microsoft guys.

You need run this batch again after you install Visual Studio updates or sometime even Windows Updates.

Answer (score 2):

I followed Yanhua's [Microsoft article link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/783668/qtagent32-35-exe-qtagent32-exe-system-executionengineexception-running-unittest-in-vs2012-2) and found a workaround that I liked better than deleting random files:

**Use vstest.console.exe instead of mstest.exe.**

Note, the arguments for vstest.console.exe are different. It wants a space-separated list of test.dll's

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" "TestProject1.dll"
```

Here is my msbuild setup that does the same thing:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <MSTEST>"$(VS110COMNTOOLS)..\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe"</MSTEST>
</PropertyGroup>
...
<Target Name="MyTests" >
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- These Items should be evaluated at Target runtime -->
    <TestFiles Include="..\Tests\**\bin\$(Configuration)\*.Test.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <!-- Run Tests -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!--TestSuccessOrNot is the property specify whether the Test is sucess or not -->
    <TestSuccessOrNot>1</TestSuccessOrNot>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Exec Command="$(MSTEST) @(TestFiles, ' ')" >
    <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="TestSuccessOrNot"/>
  </Exec>
  <Error Text="Tests Failed" Condition="$(TestSuccessOrNot) == '1'" />
</Target>
```

Comment: This is also recommended by Microsoft http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/08/19/vs-tfs-2012-4-update-4-rc-2-is-available.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. I just removed update 2 of Visual Studio 2012. 
Steps:

- Remove update 2 of Visual studio 2012 (via View installed updates)
- Restart system
- Change installation of Visual Studio 2012 (via Uninstall or change a program->change->Fix)
- Restart system