# mstest error - qtagent32.exe has stopped working

Tags: .net, mstest

I builded a simple test dll (net 3.5, Debug, x86)

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;    
namespace TestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual("111", "111");
        }
    }
}
```

when i run mstest tool from cmd:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"  /testcontainer:"TestProject1.dll"
```

i get this error:
[image]

but test works if TestProject1 will be builded with net 4.0

i have a Windows 7 Ultimate, VS 2010 and 2013 without any updates.
Can anyone help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the similar question here: [mstest.exe vs2012 crashes qtagent32.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500124/mstest-exe-vs2012-crashes-qtagent32-exe)

Note, I didn't follow any of the solutions listed, but I followed the workaround listed in [a Microsoft article](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/783668/qtagent32-35-exe-qtagent32-exe-system-executionengineexception-running-unittest-in-vs2012-2) to use vstest.console.exe instead of mstest.exe.

(also note, the arguments for vstest.console.exe are different. It wants a space-separated list of test.dll's)

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" "TestProject1.dll"
```

Here is my msbuild setup that does the same thing:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <MSTEST>"$(VS110COMNTOOLS)..\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe"</MSTEST>
</PropertyGroup>
...
<Target Name="MyTests" >
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- These Items should be evaluated at Target runtime -->
    <TestFiles Include="..\Tests\**\bin\$(Configuration)\*.Test.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <!-- Run Tests -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!--TestSuccessOrNot is the property specify whether the Test is sucess or not -->
    <TestSuccessOrNot>1</TestSuccessOrNot>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Exec Command="$(MSTEST) @(TestFiles, ' ')" >
    <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="TestSuccessOrNot"/>
  </Exec>
  <Error Text="Tests Failed" Condition="$(TestSuccessOrNot) == '1'" />
</Target>
```